# Sitecore users to add fields to template

Tags: templates, sitecore, edit

I'm building a products table to show all the products attributes. However I need to allow users to add/edit/remove those attributes from the products later on in production without any dev work. I thought about branch templates but when I edit the branch template, existing products are not getting updated. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction? Any suggestions?

Comment: Branch templates are used only as initial Sitecore values. It is a limitation of branch templates. Even if you will create your set of items from branch template, when you will try to reset values Sitecore will use "Standard values" of your templates. (but not from branch template). So, you could think how your design could be fit in one template with standard values.

Answer (score 0):

In an older project we have a similar setup with product and attributes and used a custom database to help us out:

- products are stored as items in Sitecore
- attributes are stored as items in Sitecore
- a custom database stores the values of all attributes for all products
- publish events are used to keep the custom database in sync when deleting products
- on a product template we added an extra tab in the content editor including an aspx page that offers an editor on our custom database for that product. We use the products Sitecore ID and display all possible attributes in an editable way.

Most attributes have simple string values but that is extendable. Our attributes have a type (string, bool, (multi-)list, ..) and we use that to create the editor. The lists refer back to Sitecore items (a parent is selected on the attribute item).

Adding an extra tab in the editor can be done by creating a new item in the core database (/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors) that point towards your aspx file. In the standard values of your product template, you select the created "editor" in the Appearance section. (note that this is in Sitecore 6 - might have been changed although the path to the editors is still valid)

This solution does mean that the values of your attributes are stored outside Sitecore, but it worked for our requirements.